# not able to run threads simultaneosly in python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, python-multithreading, frappe

```
from threading import Thread
import time

def Function1():
    print "11"
    print "12"
    time.sleep(5)
    print "13"
    print "14"

def Function2():
    print "21"
    print "22"
    time.sleep(10)
    print "23"
    print "24"

for i in range(3)    
    t1= Thread(target=Function1())
    t2= Thread(target=Function2())
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
```

Above program runs sequentially...

```
11
12
13
14
21
22
23
24

11
12
13
14
21
22
23
24

11
12
13
14
21
22
23
24
```

how to run two functions(threads) simultaneously?? I don't want to use multiprocessing..
I need to write python script for performance testing...for that i need threads to run simultaneously 
Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: When in doubt, blame the [GIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_interpreter_lock).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the `target=` keyword is now set to *the return value* of function. You want to have *the function itself*.
So, what is actually happening right now is:

1. Call `Function1()`
2. `t1` has its target set to `None` (return value of `Function1()`
3. 1-2 repeated for `Function2()` and `t2`.
4. Start `t1` and `t2` threads, which both has `None` as target. This has no effect.

Replace

```
t1= Thread(target=Function1())
t2= Thread(target=Function2())
```

with

```
t1= Thread(target=Function1)
t2= Thread(target=Function2)
```

If you want parallel execution of Python code on multiple cores, then your only hope is `multiprocessing`. Since, as mentioned in another answer, the CPython interpreter only allows to execute one piece of Python code at the same time (see "Global Interpreter Lock").
There is a lot of information about this to be found online.

Comment: t1= Thread(target=Function1) in this case how can I send parameters to Function1 ??

Comment: You use the `args=` keyword parameter. See the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

> how to run two functions(threads) simultaneously? I don't want to use multiprocessing..

Unfortunately, you can't really have these two simultaneously (or at least, you can't run things truly concurrently using `threading`). This is an [inherent limitation of the CPython interpreter's GIL](http://jessenoller.com/blog/2009/02/01/python-threads-and-the-global-interpreter-lock).

The only thing that `threading` gives is single-core context switching, where the interpreter will run a function on a single core, then swap it out temporarily and run a different function on single core, etc. This is possibly useful for applications that do something while, e.g., monitoring user input, but that's about it.